# How to copy data from one sheet using column name and paste to another sheet with same column name?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to copy data from one Excel sheet by using "column name" and paste that data to another sheet with same column name using VBA. I am using Excel 2016.

I don't want to use column letter as reference while copying data. I want to use column name, since my sheet keeps changing.

Comment: Tons of question and corresponding solutions already available in SO for this very subject. Just spend some (little) time more to search for it

Comment: You could use [the `Find` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-find-method-excel) to locate the column, and then [the `Copy`method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-copy-method-excel) to copy & paste.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function takes as parameters the sheet in which you're searching for the column name and the column name you're searching for. It returns zero, if you enter an invalid name:

```
 Function FindColumnName(rng As Range, colName As String) As Long

    On Error Resume Next
    FindColumnName = rng.Find(What:=colName, _
        Lookat:=xlWhole, _
        LookIn:=xlValues, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
        MatchCase:=True).Column
End Function
```

For instance, if the column name "Test" is present in row one of column G, invoke the function like this

```
FindColumnName(ActiveSheet.Rows(1), "Test") ' change sheet name as required
```

and it will return "7".

With regards to the copy-paste part of your question, simply record a macro and go from there.

Comment: Thank you so much  for your solutuon.

Comment: Can you please help me, and could you  please provide solution for copying the data of column using above function and pasting it's data in another in another sheet with same column name.

Comment: Recording a macro which does this should be fairly simple. Just post another question with the code if you encounter problems with that. Also read this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-copy-method-excel